# StopWatch returns 0ms when having two instances of watch

Tags: c#

I am trying to measure running times of two functions, i put timers in both of them. But if I run these consecutively second returns 0ms, why is that ?

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace TestParallelLoops
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            first();
            second();
        }

        static void first()
        {
            var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            Console.WriteLine(fibonacci(50));

            watch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
        }

        static void second()
        {
            var watch1 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            watch1.Start();

            Console.WriteLine(fibonacciRecursive(50));

            watch1.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time: {watch1.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
        }

        static long fibonacci(int n)
        {
            Dictionary<int, long> last = new Dictionary<int, long>();

            last[0] = 0;
            last[1] = 1;
            int next = 2;

            while (next<=n)
            {
                last[next] = last[next-1] + last[next-2];
                next++;
            }

            return last[n];
        }

        static long fibonacciRecursive (int n)
        {
            if (n == 0) return 1;
            if (n == 1) return 1;

            return fibonacciRecursive(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
        }


    }
}
```

If i execute only first i see ~100 ms if i execute only second i see ~100ms but if i execute both i see ~100 ms and 0ms.

Many thanks

Comment: Use the `Frequency` and `IsHighResolution` fields to determine the precision and resolution of the Stopwatch timing implementation.

Comment: Why are you calling `fibonacci()` from your `fibonacciRecursive` method? Shouldn't it call it `fibonacciRecursive` as well?

Comment: I ran your code and executed the functions in a for loop for like a 100 times. And it does show me a lot of 0ms and sometimes 1ms and even 7ms. Either it runs so fast, or I am not seeing something. But it's not always 0ms.

Comment: Benchmarking successfully is hard; you have to make sure you are measuring *only* the stuff you want to measure. Also remember: the first time a piece of code runs, *you are measuring the cost of loading that code off disk and jitting it*. Do you intend to measure that cost? If not, make sure you don't measure the code on the first time it runs!

Answer (score 3):

Dustin S. is likely on the money with the first `Console.WriteLine` causing the initial 100ms hit. Changing up main to

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Here we go!");
    first();
    second();
}
```

Tends to yield results of 0 ms for both, given how fast the machine running it is, and whatever the underlying precision of the StopWatch is.

Your `fibanacciResursive` call isn't full recursive, it should likely have the following `return`:

```
return fibonacciRecursive(n - 1) + fibonacciRecursive(n - 2);
```

Which takes <s>~2s (I'd lowered the value to 45)</s> longer than I'd like to wait to evaluate for a value of 50 on my machine, since this isn't caching intermediary results and duplicates a lot of effort.

The recusive implementation you have does have another issue with the guards that is causing it to actually return the `n + 1`th fibonacci number, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

In any case, given the current implementation of `fibonacci` and `fibonacciRecursive` (without the fix mentioned above), a 0ms result for both with a value as small as 50 sounds right for most machines.

Comment: Hey i fixed the error of using the nonrecursive function in the second case. However interesting finding is that the recursive function is very fast until we are looking for 35+ fibonacci sequence and it results 0ms. However after 35 there is a significant difference between the dict and the recursive :. 
  
  Here we go!
Operations timed using the system's high-resolution performance counter.
  Timer frequency in ticks per second = 1000000000
  Timer is accurate within 1 nanoseconds
9227465
Execution Time: 36 ms
9227465
Execution Time: 451 ms

Press any key to continue...

Answer (score 2):

I think your 100ms is probably the time it takes to unblock the console. Save the value off and write the console outside of your timed block like this (do same for first() method):

```
    static void second()
    {
        var watch1 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        watch1.Start();
        var a = fibonacciRecursive(50);
        watch1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time: {watch1.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }
```